ORIGAMI PUZZLES completed version
You may have seen some posts by Sunny Lu here on my origami puzzles. Now, the full version is out!
The goal is to fold the paper into a rectangle (or square) with
constant thickness (see examples), and the game contains 30 puzzles with increasing cursedness. Trust me, you'll definitely feel the cursedness towards the end.
Puzzles are very approximately ordered by difficulty. Stars mark puzzles that are much harder than they are expected to be.
Partial answers are allowed.
Edit: here's an extra challenge! See puzzle 14 (the cross shaped advanced puzzle) and puzzle 29 (the 101 thickness)? Prove that puzzle 14 is solvable for all thickness >1, and puzzle 29 is solvable for all thickness >3.



Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! I've made your puzzle self-contained, which means that it no longer relies on external resources.

The top right was actually easier than I expected

The little number in each picture represents the number of layers in the solution? Is that supposed to be 57 and 101 in the bottom row? Otherwise I can solve all the puzzles aligned with the grid by just layering everything on a single grid square which makes them fairly trivial.

Yes. @quarague.

@PDT probably for the best...

Ok the second starred puzzle is one tough SOB how is it even possible? I think it is worthy of a post in and of itself.

@PDT if you read the text, advanced puzzles are only advanced because they are RELATIVELY hard. Puzzle 5 is advanced because it really is a jump in execution from the previous 5, but it doesn't mean it's hard.

@PDT how's it going?

@SunnyLu any tips on how to solve the octagon with the hole in the middle. Like do I diagonals.

no u dont have to do diagonals

Also, just in case this wasn't clear enough, please do not view the solutions and paste them here. :)

as a minimum, the solution must be hand-drawn, either on a drawing app or on paper, in a style different from my pdf.

@sny am I allowed to have a square with a giant hole in the middle with no paper.

FYI just solved the cross once I got paper!!

how much is the advertisement space?

@PDT no, the square must be completely filled.

@dhuang it's just a joke

@Sny progress so far super fun but I lack the time and motivation to finish the rest
https://i.sstatic.net/8M9qt86T.jpg
https://i.sstatic.net/pzBRBiHf.jpg

is there a tag for sarcasm? /s
fun puzzle btw!

@PDT nice!!!!!!

@PDT congrats! that one is difficult... i almost feel guilty for putting it there (which is the reason why advanced puzzles were invented in the first place)

Guys, remember, partial solutions are great!

@Sny I will post where I have got to so far… I got all of the straight puzzles bar the octagon.

For the octagon, look a the the 2nd of the 2nd row for inspiration.

Do the little hexagonal icons on some of the shapes mean anything?

It symbolizes puzzles made by me :)

Here are my partial answers.  With some differences from PDT's.
Fold on the blue lines.
Row 1, #1 to #5

 

Row 2, #6 to #10

 

Row 3, #11 to #15

 

Row 4, #16 to #20

 

Row 5, #21 to #25

 

PS: I removed a wrong solution and fixed another one.
Then I had a look at the solutions, so I will stop here.

Ahh shoot I did think of that for 10!!! It’s just the paper had made the rectangle look seriously uneven!!

I also had to use paper for #10.

good job for 10!!! finally :)
please redo puzzle 20 for a more elegant solution lmao (it's like puzzle 10)
and hmmm feedback here may force me to make puzzle 21 advanced too, i've seen a ton of people get stuck on that.
funny: all of them are multistep, except for 13 (which i seriously thought it was easier than 14, so maybe i need to change the order too)
nevertheless, good job! i appreciate the dedication to this one post, especially since it contains a lot of puzzle for a typical pse post (i considered splitting up but i would overload the question menu so i decided against it)

I already looked at your solutions.  So I could amend #20 but it would be just copying yours.

I erased #13 because of a silly mistake.  It didn't make a rectangle.  I would probably have found it.  This being said, #14 was one of the easy ones for me.

For the top half this is my progress so far:
Row 1 (complete)

 For puzzle 2, the folds are in order of ROYGBIV:
 

Row 2: Last is still unsolved and also added steps for 1 and 4 for clarity:

 
 1.

 4.


Row 3 (complete)

 1.

 2.

 3.

 4.

 5.



Any tips on how to solve the octagon it’s really tough…?

Reduction is your friend

wow cool! you found a unintended solution for puzzle 11, but that's fine :)
it's related to puzzle 10, so once you're done with that maybe try go back to find the intended solution :)

@Omega_3301 I have been trying to solve it for a while now. To no avail!

@Omega_3301 I don’t see how there are only straight line folds!

@PDT think in steps, and yes there are diagonals... i don't know who told you there are only orthogonals
so basically it's a multistep puzzle: you need to make some folds to reduce the puzzle to a thickness 2 that's solvable.

@Omega_3301 the best I have got is a square of 4x paper thickness with a hole in the middle.

@PDT if you need a hint, you did the next puzzle wrongly too; there's a far more elegant solution, which was supposed to be discovered after this puzzle.
do you have a discord account? this comment thread is getting long and i also want feedback on origami puzzles :)

Inelegant doesn't mean wrong.  My #11 iis worse than PDT's but it still works.

@FlorianF have you worked out 10?

@PDT Yes.  Look at #7 for inspiration.

@FlorianF regarding inelegancy of solutions: yes i know, it's still correct. the only reason why i'm stating that is because i feel that the aha moment of an elegant solution is worth the extra time spent
regarding puzzle 7... i'm changing that one in the itch.io copy soon, so sorry! (it was my first origami puzzle and i'm sad to see it go, but it wasn't a good puzzle thematically with the multistep solution and the unintended solution (hint: see puzzle 8).

My (still incomplete) set of solution.
I assume the 'simultaneous folds' at 10 and 30 are allowed?!
(note: blue folds before green)

 

Nr 10 more detailed:

 


Happy to see new variations for some of them.

woah... i definitely didn't expect that for puzzle 10... i knew it was possible, but i just thought nobody would come up with it until puzzle 30! good job!
and as for the 3 uncompleted puzzles... yes they're hard, and you don't need to feel sad for not solving them. if you have a discord we could discuss more about them!
edit: wait could you recheck your puzzle 10 solution? i think it's incorrect

@Omega_3301 I added more detail for 10; seems OK to me.

@Retudin ahhh i didn't see the diagram properly; it's definitely correct! once again good job for finding this solution (this idea was meant to be reserved for puzzle 30)
